# Allow a group to upload files on an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After a group trip abroad, I would like to gather the photos & videos that everybody took. I have an Amazon S3 account, how can I use it to allow people to send files to it ?

Most people in the group are not "power users" so I'd like the process to be as simple as possible.

Ideally, I would have an url that I'd share with the others, where they can select and upload multiple files to my bucket. They would not have access to the rest of my AWS account. It could require a simple password, but that's not mandatory, I'll ask the group not to share the URL.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but not out-of-the-box.  You would have to set up your own web server providing that URL and then relaying all uploaded stuff into your S3 bucket.

The AWS API for S3 does not provide any means of allowing roles or groups or similar complex things.  The standalone solution would therefore be to give your group members the S3 access credentials, but handling them correctly would not be an easy task for them.  Maybe if you give them a script to use for this.  But that again is neither out-of-the-box nor fit for non-power-users.